# Android Keyboard with custom layout

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

I read most of the tutorials to make a SoftKeyboard for Android and all of them talking about using `android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView` and `xml` file with `Keyboard` element to make the keyboard.
The `Keyboard` element only accepts `row` as child and `row` only accepts `key` so I can't add another UI components like `EditText` or any other UI components.
At first I though that can't be done but during my search I found this [keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.emoji.ikeyboard) which has search and search results in the keyboard.
So how can I make a custom keyboard layout like this?